# how to extract indices from 2D original numpy array X based on conditions on same size array Y

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 numpy arrays `x_original` and `y_original` each 50x12060 float numbers representing X and Y values that can be plotted on X-Y coordinates.

I can use a filter condition on Y values like `filteredY = np.nonzero((y_original > threshold_y)+0)` to get the tuple `filteredY` whose first `filteredY[0]` is a list of rows from `y_original` and whose second elements `filteredY[1]` is a list of columns from `y_original` for which the numbers in `y_original` are larger than a number `threshold_y` (filter condition). Then, `x_original[filteredY[0],filteredY [1]]` gives out values from `x_original` that correspond  to those `y_original` elements which are larger than `threshold_y` (that is X values for those Y values which pass the filter condition). Finally, `np.amax(x_original[filteredY[0],filteredY [1]])` gives the maximum of values from `x_original` for which the `y_original` elements which are larger than `threshold_y` (largest X value for which the Y value condition holds).
However, I want to obtain which index (row, column) in the **original array** `x_original` is the one for which `x_original==np.amax(x_original[filteredY[0],filteredY [1]])` and also `y_original > threshold_y`. That is I want to find the index "i" of `x_original` whose corresponding `y_original[i] > threshold_y` and `x_original[i]` is the largest of X values for which the filter condition on Y holds.

I tried `np.argmax(x_original[filteredY[0],filteredY [1]])` which does not work directly as it returns indices from a filtered `x_original` and not `x_original` itself. I also tried `np.argwhere(x_original==np.amax(x_original[filteredY[0],filteredY [1]]))` fut that returns all X values which equal `np.amax(x_original[filteredY[0],filteredY [1]])` and is independent of condition on Y.

Comment: I have trouble separating what is your need and what is your attemp. I propose creating simple example with input and output.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.logical_and(x_original ==np.amax(x_original[filteredY]),  y_original >threshold_y).nonzero()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.